# How do AVs scan the file in websites that claim they don't send the files to AVs like Nodistribute.com?

Tags: malware, virus, antivirus, antimalware

So for example one of the famous alternatives to Virustotal aka Nodistribute.com claims that it doesn't send the file to AVs, but if it doesn't, then how can they scan it? **just by checking the hash? if so, wouldn't that make the scan pretty much useless?**

and if it does send the file to them, then what's the difference between this site and Virustotal?

Comment: http://the11hacker.blogspot.com/2016/09/nodistributecom-is-fake-it-shares.html

Comment: @VipulNair I updated the question, I'm asking generally about websites that claim they dont send the samples to AVs, for example the site you mentioned claims another one is safe : https://the11hacker.blogspot.com/2017/07/nosharescanner-is-it-fake-shares-samples.html.  BUT how does it work if it doesnt send the sample to AVs?

Comment: I have no idea how websites implement.But if i were to implement it and keep to my promise of not sending samples to AV vendors.

 1. Create a sandbox Virtual machine.
 2. Download the latest versions of antiviruses.
 3. Cut it off the internet.
 4. Scan the file
 5. Delete the file
 6. Periodically update the antivirus.

Comment: Reason i dont answer is i could be wrong.So just a comment.

Comment: @VipulNair do you know any website that operates that way or at least claim to operate that way?

Comment: No.I know of no such site.Also such an implmentation wont have reliable results because a lot of AV is based on signature based analysis which would require internet

Comment: You appear to be assuming that all of these sites do things the same way. I'm not sure you can make that assumption. I think the best you can do is determine how each one does it. BTW, Nodistribute does not use TLS, so every file you send is exposed, and the core API it used went down last year. So, it's not going to work anyway.

Comment: nosharescanner.com also appears to not work

Comment: @OneAndOnly the FAQ for Nodistribute explains your question. It doesn't send the files to AV vendors. It sends it, using an API, to a service that checks it against AV engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that they send the files, the reason I think they do is because in the past there was a site that was well known for not sending the files.

It was most known by malware builders, their owners end up with problems with justice accused of helping malicious actors and allowing them to tune their malware, basically partners in crime.

You can search for reFUD-dot-me

If they are really doing it, there is a good chance they will end up as the  reFUD...

https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/02/15/refud_cryptex_kingpin_goncalo_esteves_jailed/

Or

https://www.zdnet.com/article/hacker-gets-a-whopping-14-years-in-prison-for-running-scan4you-service/

Comment: But HOW would they do it without sending the file to AVs? just use a hash checking or..?

Comment: No they can use antivirus API in isolated machines. You can do it for example, build a vmware farm with multiple windows system each using a version of av that you can use the API to pass the parameters from a source.

Comment: Improving my previous comment... They can use antivirus API in isolated machines. (I do not know exactly how it is done so there is a probability of error) I will start with the following logic,  e.g.: build a vmware farm with multiple windows systems each using a version of av that you can use the API to pass the files and get the results from each one. Example on API: https://www.kaspersky.com/antivirus-sdk, the other vendors might have the same.